# Resize DIV from either side, not just the corner

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to resize a DIV, from anywhere, and not just from the corners.

I used css code:

```
resize: horizontal;
```

My div, look like this

[image: my div, look like this]

But I want something, Like this (resize like sulime text)
[image]

Is there any way to do this, like some javascript function?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
```

It will let you resize the `div` both horizontally and  Vertically from Bottom Right Corner.
Hope this might help to some extent.

Comment: They want to drag and resize the div by the edges, not just one corner.